# How to add tooltips to each item of a cluster in Folium?

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, geojson, geopandas, folium

**INTRO**: I have a geopandas dataframe `df_osm` (points and polygons) like so:

```
geometry                                              name
0  POLYGON ((1.46423 43.56901, 1.46428 43.56847, ...  A
1  POLYGON ((1.38403 43.60532, 1.38319 43.60517, ...  B
2  POLYGON ((1.48632 43.53240, 1.48744 43.53285, ...  C
3  POLYGON ((1.40321 43.57974, 1.40315 43.57974, ...  D
4  POLYGON ((1.46420 43.57225, 1.46553 43.57278, ...  E
```

My goal is to make a folium map using clusters. I am able to create the map with the following lines of code and everything looks to be working fine:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[df_cdm.latitude.mean(),df_cdm.longitude.mean()], zoom_start=15, tiles='CartoDB positron', max_zoom = 20)

m_cluster = MarkerCluster(name='OSM').add_to(m)
for i, row in df_osm.iterrows():
    
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(row['geometry'])
    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                           style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
    geo_j.add_to(m_cluster)

m
```

[image]

**QUESTION**: My goal is to add a tooltip to each item of the dataframe displaying its name. While reading in the internet I found out that I should include in the `folium.GeoJson` function the following entry:

```
tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['name'])
```

However when I display the map all the polygons and markers do not have any tooltip. Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer just a repeatable MWE.  Used **geopandas** natural earth cities as data

Observations

1. add markers without `MarkerCluster` hover works, shows the city name and it's assigned cluster
2. add markers in `MarkerCluster` no hover using exactly same code to build them
3. add markers to both, layer control shows them all.  Hover is only shown if layers are clicked on

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely.ops
import folium, folium.plugins

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# sample some points to make a voronoi to cluster points
r = np.random.RandomState(13)
gdf_ = gdf.sample(5, random_state=r)

gdf_clusters = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(
        shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(gdf_.dissolve()["geometry"].values[0]).geoms
    ),
    crs=gdf_.crs,
)

gdf = (
    gpd.sjoin(gdf, gdf_clusters)
    .rename(columns={"index_right": "cluster"})
    .sort_values(["cluster", "name"])
)

# add some columns for hover...
gdf_clusters = gdf_clusters.join(
    gdf.groupby("cluster").agg(first=("name", "first"), last=("name", "last"))
)

# create folium map, simple way
m = gdf_clusters.reset_index().explore(name="polys")

# cluster the points added to marker clusters...
for c, d in gdf.groupby("cluster"):
    m_c = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(name=f"mc: {c}").add_to(m)
    fields = d.drop(columns="geometry").columns.tolist()
    markers = folium.GeoJson(
        name = f"m: {c}",
        data=d.__geo_interface__,
        tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields),

    )
    markers.add_to(m_c) 
    # markers.add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

#### update

- tooltips don't work with markers created with `GeoJson()` and marker clusters
- they do work with individually created `Marker()`.  Code below shows how to do this

```
# cluster the points added to marker clusters...
for c, d in gdf.groupby("cluster"):
    m_c = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster(name=f"mc: {c}")
    for _, row in d.iterrows():
        folium.Marker(
            location=[row.geometry.y, row.geometry.x],
            tooltip=f"""<b>name</b>: {row["name"]}""",
        ).add_to(m_c)

    m_c.add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly it does not perform the goal that I am trying to do. As stated in the question: "My goal is to add a tooltip to each item of the dataframe displaying its name." In your example instead the tooltip is applied just to the cluster polygons.  The image I posted instead I should see a different tooltip for each item whether it is a polygon or a point.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I stated.  However you presented only images, not code that reproduces the situation.  I've re-used code out of libraries that create markers,  however whenever they are clustered there is no tooltip.  possible work raising an issue on GitHub against folium with a fully working code example

Comment: went back to basics and used `Marker()` instead of `GeoJson()` and have now created multiple marker clusters with markers that have tooltips

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following trick:

- Split geopandas dataframe in 2

  - List of points
  - List of polygons

Then plot them separetely:

```
mask = df_osm['geometry'].geom_type=='Point'
df_osm_point = df_osm[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
df_osm_polygons = df_osm[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally plot everything separately:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import BeautifyIcon, MarkerCluster, Fullscreen

cols = df_osm.columns[1:] # Exclude geometry column

m = folium.Map(location=[df_cdm.latitude.mean(),df_cdm.longitude.mean()], zoom_start=15, tiles='CartoDB positron', max_zoom = 20)

m_cluster = MarkerCluster(name='OSM').add_to(m)
for i, row in df_osm_point.iterrows():
    
    tooltip = ""
    for col in cols:
        if row[col]!='':
            tooltip += f"<b>{col}</b>: {row[col]}<br>"
    
    folium.Marker(location=[row['latitude'], row['longitude']],
                  tooltip=tooltip).add_to(m_cluster)

    
for _, row in df_osm_polygons.iterrows():
    
    tooltip = ""
    for col in cols:
        if row[col]!='':
            tooltip += f"<b>{col}</b>: {row[col]}<br>"
            
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(row['geometry']).simplify(tolerance=0.001)
    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                           style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
    folium.Tooltip(tooltip).add_to(geo_j)
    geo_j.add_to(m)


m_cluster = MarkerCluster(name='OTHER').add_to(m)
for i, row in df_cdm.iterrows():
    
    tooltip = f"""<p><b>Source</b>: {row['source']}<br>
                  <b>name</b>: {row['name']}<br>
                  <b>address</b>: {row['address']}<br>
                  <b>website</b>: {row['website']}<br>
                  <b>latitude</b>: {row['latitude']}<br>
                  <b>longitude</b>: {row['longitude']}</p>"""
    
    folium.Marker(location=[row['latitude'], row['longitude']],
                  tooltip=tooltip,
                  icon=folium.Icon(color='green',icon_color='black')).add_to(m_cluster)

Fullscreen(position='topright',
force_separate_button=True
).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```